# Compare strings with a wildcard operator (*) and randomized order — Anagrams

Tags: c

I have two strings, I want to know if they are equal to each other. However the strings character-order has been randomized. Also certain characters may have been swapped out with a wildcard operator (*). I'm using this for Anagram detection.

---

In this case, I'm trying to get the anagram program I have to say that ab** is an anagram of abba. Right now it can tell if its an anagram if it is literally an anagram like abba and bbaa.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to implement wildcard *'s and I have no idea where to start, please help!

What i have so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define SIZE 5



bool areAnagram(char *str1, char *str2)
{

    int count[SIZE] = {0};
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; str1[i] && str2[i];  i++)
    {
        count[str1[i]]++;
        count[str2[i]]--;
    }

    if (str1[i] || str2[i])
    {
         return false;
    }



    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (count[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

     return true;
}

int main()
{
    char str1[SIZE], str2[SIZE];

    FILE *finput;

    finput = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    fscanf(finput, "%s %s", str1, str2);

    printf("%s\n", str1);
    printf("%s\n", str2);

  if(areAnagram(str1, str2))
  {
        printf("THEY ARE ANAGRAMS\n");
  }
  else
  {
      printf("THEY AREN'T ANAGRAMS\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler abba and bbaa are anagrams, which is what the input.txt is set to

Comment: Oh now I now what you mean.  ya thats a broken code whoops brb

Comment: `abaa` `baba` - `THEY ARE ANAGRAMS` - no they're still not? You're initializing `count[SIZE]` a 5 element array, indexes 0,1,2,3,4. Then you're indexing into it with `count[str1[i]]` - str1 is a character array, so the letter `a` is going to be ASCII character number 97, so you're doing `count[97]` of an array which goes 0-4. I think you're chewing through random unallocated memory. Then you try to look for the results in the five places of `count[i]`. This approach might work if you made count big enough and changed the counters, but right now it's fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how selection-sort algorithm works, but instead of checking integer value to arrange I'll just use a string comparison to select/remove and add an exception for (*). Iterate through the whole list and viola!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char inputString[] = "AB**";//input string (with asterisks)
    char comparisonString[] = "AYYB";//comparison string (without asterisks)

    int inputString_length = strlen(inputString);
    int comparisonString_length = strlen(comparisonString);

    int anagram = 1;//boolean

    if (inputString_length != comparisonString_length) {
        anagram = 0;
    } else {

        int i = 0;
        while ((i < inputString_length) && (anagram == 1)) {

            char *letterToCheck = inputString[0];
            memmove(&inputString[0], &inputString[0 + 1], strlen(inputString) - 0);//remove first character

            int j = 0;
            int comparisonString_length_new = strlen(comparisonString);
            int matchFound = 0;//boolean
            while ((j < comparisonString_length_new) && (matchFound == 0)) {
                char *letterToCompare = comparisonString[j];

                if (letterToCheck == '*') {
                    matchFound = 1;
                }

                if (letterToCheck == letterToCompare) {
                    matchFound = 1;
                    memmove(&comparisonString[j], &comparisonString[j + 1], strlen(comparisonString) - j);//remove matched character
                }

                j++;
            }

            if (matchFound == 0) {
                anagram = 0;
            }


            i++;
        }

    }


    if (anagram == 0) {
        printf("Are NOT Anagrams");
    } else {
        printf("Are Anagrams");
    }

}
```

Another solution where both input and comparison strings may contain * (Note: This solution below was added by an off-site user and not OP, it has also not been tested nor verified by OP)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHAR_LEN 4
#define SPECIAL_CHARACTER '*'

int count_special_char(char *string) {
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < CHAR_LEN; i++) {
        if(string[i] == SPECIAL_CHARACTER)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int is_anagram(char *string_a, char *string_b) {
    int i, y;
    int found_count = 0;
    int a_special = count_special_char(string_a);
    int b_special = count_special_char(string_b);

    for(i = 0; i < CHAR_LEN; i++) {
        if(string_a[i] == SPECIAL_CHARACTER) //compare only non-asterisk char
            continue;

        for(y = 0; y < CHAR_LEN; y++) {
            if(string_a[i] == string_b[y]) {
                string_b[y] = '\0' //treat this char as found
                found_count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if((found_count + a_special + b_special) >= CHAR_LEN)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main() {
    char a[CHAR_LEN] = "**CD";
    char b[CHAR_LEN] = "AB**";

    if(is_anagram(a, b))
        printf("yes\n");
    else
        printf("no\n");

    return 0;
}
```

A*** and *XYZ is assumed as anagram because first string has 3 * which can represent second string XYZ. And second string has 1 * which can represent first string A. If there are any mistakes do point out and help. Thanks!

Comment: In the first solution I get an error at 

`char *letterToCheck = str1[0];`

saying that it is an incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *'

Comment: @Vcoss Did you copy paste it directly into a new project to test? I just copy pasted it into an online C IDE and it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

On Linux and Posix systems, you might use globbing related functions. See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) and look into [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), [fnmatch(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html), [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) etc

Look also into [regcomp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html)

If you need to write it by yourself, read about [finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), [context free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), [regular grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar), [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Comment: By `'*'` OP means a single character. Isn't it? In regex `'*'` may stand for any number of characters.